# Check existence of any receipt item related to the order

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, xrm, xrmservicetoolkit

Here is a question.
Every order has some `receipt item` and it has 1(`order`) to N(`receipt item`) relation with receipt item.
I wanna check that if there is any record  in `receipt item` of `order` entity or not.
How can it be possible?
I do like this happen in onload of the order and via JS, not workflow or something like that.
I wanna set  a button to Enable/Disable if there is any receipt item, so I need onload JS.
Is it possible? If yes how?
Any help or link? or sample?

Note that I have installed CRM 2011 on-permise.

Comment: [Jason Lattimer's CRMRESTBuilder](https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder) can help you build the query you're looking for.

Comment: It's definitely possible. You're using CRM 2011, so quite old. Try to build the query you want in FetchXml first, then you can use JavaScript to execute the same query

Answer (score 0):

Use the REST endpoint to get the data in javascript. There is plenty of exemple on the web.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamics-crm2011/developers-guide/gg334279(v=crm.5)

Your query shoud look like this:
[Your Organization Root URL]/xrmservices/2011/organizationdata.svc/salesorderdetails/?$select=[Put the columns you want]&$filter=orderid eq (guid'" + orderId + "')